# Solution to Not-Yet-Supported Country for Android Market Merchandise

Tags: android, google-play

I wish to sell paid applications via Android Market, however my country (Slovakia) is not in the list of entitled countries(http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324).

Could I temporarily overcome this limitation by getting a bank account and a paycard from a bank within the country(Austria in my case) entitled for Android Market merchandise?

Do you know, whether the Android Market merchants are allowed to use the store based on the location of their bank, their residence encoded in the card, or the internet connection location?

Solving this would help many others wishing to distribute paid apps but their country has not yet been allowed for Android Market merchandise.

Comment: Better ask the Android guys about that.

Comment: Hi Sims, gladly, I asked in Android Market forums yesterday, but no response so far. Nobody apparently knew in IRC #Android #Android-dev channels. This place was listed as Google recommended Android source of information. Do you know where else to ask, please?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem ? Does opening bank account in another country work (for Google Market) ?

Comment: closed as off topic by user7116, Robert Harvey <- You are a JOKE guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think technically you could just open a bank account in an entitled country, lie about your address and use that to take payments, but there might be legal issues around this.

What could be a solution is to open a company too and register that legal entity as a developer, but unless you anticipate massive sales this might be a bit too much effort, even with all the administration easing you get if you do it in an other EU country.

Comment: Hi Dain, if I am correct, I will have to provide my real address to the bank, where I open a bank account. So this soultion would work, if the Android Market merchants are checked only on country location of their bank. Another alternative would be estabilishing a company, but as you said, this would be beneficial only if high sales are anticipated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you actually have to be a permanent resident under the address you want to open the account with, so if you have someone in an eligible country you could use their address for correspondence.

Comment: Hi @Bunkai.Satori could you let me know if you made this work? I live in Slovenia and I'm also thinking about doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

There is really no direct way to sell apps on Android Market if your country is not listed there. However, you can check out www.androidconnector.com, a US based company that will help you with just that.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer.. I checked www.androidconnector.com, and apparently, it serves just to this purpose. Honestly, I am not really sure, if I can trust third party, related money.

Comment: Problem with such reseller is that its name appear as developer of the app on Market, its other apps are listed in "More from developer", and your (real developer's) name is not being promoted so good.